# Magento 2.4.0 sort products by is_salable on product list

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.0

I want to products on product list will always be sorted from salable to not salable. Products which have "Add to cart" button should be show firstly(It should work for simple and configurable products)

I tried created plugin as is written in [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178061/magento2-sort-products-and-search-result-by-stock-availability][1] :

`//di.xml`

```
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
            <plugin name="product_sort_by_stock" type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Layer"/>
    </type>
```

`//app/code/Company/Module/Model/Plugin/Layer.php`

```
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin;
    
    class Layer
    {
    
        public function aroundgetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
        {
            $selectedDirection = 'DESC';
            $collection = $proceed();
            $collection->getSelect()->order('is_salable '. $selectedDirection);
            return $collection;
        }
    }
```

But it not works for me. Products are not sorted in a correct order.

Could you advice me how to  sort product collection by `is_salable` attribute? I have Magento 2.4.0 and Elasticsearch 7.9.2. I use multi source inventory.
[1]: [Magento2 sort products and search result by stock availability](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178061/magento2-sort-products-and-search-result-by-stock-availability)

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to do this? I am in a similar situation and see that I have to add is_salable attribute to the elastic search bucket list before searching / sorting ? It seems that stock_status is general and not per store view in the bucket

Comment: I have the same issue. Please let me know if you get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
         ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'], 
         "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", ['is_in_stock']
  );
  $collection->getSelect()->order(['is_in_stock desc']);
```

Refernce: [Magento2 Display out of stock products at last](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228821/magento2-display-out-of-stock-products-at-last)